# alter style definition in vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin7

I have code that will hide components dynamically; it uses [component].addStyleName("name") to add a style to a component, and that style is defined to hide the component.

I have a page which will have a large number of components; I can put them in an array and do this, but I'm hoping for a different way. I would like to assign all those components their own style - something like "costPanel" - and then use server-side vaadin code to alter the definition of the style "costPanel" at runtime.

The `Page.Styles` class in Vaadin has no methods for obtaining existing styles nor altering ones that are there -- the only methods are for adding them.

Is this possible in Vaadin, even if I have to do something on the client side for it?

Comment: **1)** Why not simply use `component.setVisible(true/false);`?. **2)** It's not very clear what you mean by `altering the style`... like adding or removing styles defined in your theme to components, or _physically_ changing the definition of a style?

Comment: It would be miles better to use component.setVisible(true/false); components you've set to visible false using component.setVisible(false); are not sent out to the browser at all, so would be more efficient, especially if you have lots of hidden components.

Comment: To both Morfic and Chris M - guess I did not make it clear, I want these elements to take up no space until they are revealed, and for them to be revealed and hidden at runtime. I the CSS style addition & removal will do what I want, but I was hoping I could set a style on each component and then change the definition of the style at runtime, instead of adding and removing the style name from the component at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perhaps best suited as a comment, but it does not really fit in there.

Not trying to be patronising, but it sounds like you're trying in a very complicated way to *reinvent the wheel*. `component.setVisible(false)` will do exactly what you need, as in the component will not take up any space since it won't actually exist in the DOM itself. Take a look at the example below:

Code:

```
public class LayoutWithInvisibleComponents extends VerticalLayout {
    private int index = 0;

    public LayoutWithInvisibleComponents() {
        // add a visibility toggling button
        addComponent(new Button("Toggle next", event -> {
            Component component = getComponent(++index);
            if (component instanceof Button) {
                // just toggle the next one if it's a button
                component.setVisible(!component.isVisible());
            }
            if (index == getComponentCount() - 1) {
                // reset counter
                index = 0;
            }
        }));

        // add some invisible dummy buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Button button = new Button("Button " + i);
            button.setVisible(false);
            addComponent(button);
        }

        // and add a visual delimiter
        Panel rightPanel = new Panel(new Label("---------- some visual delimiter ----------"));
        rightPanel.setSizeFull();
        addComponent(rightPanel);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: DOM modifications]

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Sharing a bit more about setVisible() in another answer-that-isn't-an-answer below. Many thanks.

Comment: @arcy no problem, glad you sorted it out. However, I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean with the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

This also would make a better comment, but doesn't fit well enough there.

The following is from the Book of Vaadin:

```
Beware that invisible beings can leave footprints. The containing layout cell that holds the invisible
component will not go away, but will show in the layout as extra empty space. Also expand ratios
work just like if the component was visible - it is the layout cell that expands, not the component.
```

The phrase "show in the layout as extra empty space" convinced me that there would be blank, open, background-colored space where my component was supposed to be. I don't remember if I tried it, but I might have and had some other error that caused me to conclude my assumption was correct, and that the setting was for making it un-rendered but with the space still visible.

Vaadin has much better documentation than most of the industry, but in this case I got the meaning crossed up. In succeeding paragraphs they even have additional explanation that does say what I learned through this question, but the part quoted here seemed to contradict it.

Comment: Now I finally understood your comment :-) It would be helpful if you could also link to the _clear it up_ section from the book, just for future references

Comment: Looking in the PDF version of the book, I don't see something called "Clear it up" -- where is that?

Comment: Ah. How quickly one forgets what one wrote. Yes, in the paragraphs following the explanation I quoted, they 'explain' further, and actually say what you said about setVisible(). I missed that the first time around because I was confused by the original explanation. I'll reword my answer to make that more clear. Thanks again.